How to access user and role information in superset using API in Python?
import requests
import json

superset_url = 'http://internal-k8s-devsuper-ingressd-819cadde89-967291555.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com'

login_url = f'{superset_url}/api/v1/security/login'
csrf_url = f'{superset_url}/api/v1/security/csrf_token'
api_url = f'{superset_url}/api/v1/role' 


#session request
session = requests.Session()

myusername = 'Username'
mypassword = 'Password' 

#Payload for login request
payload = {
    'username': myusername,
    'password': mypassword,
    'provider' : 'db', 
    'refresh': True  # Get refresh token along with access token
}

#Headers
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

#Login
login_res = session.post(login_url, json=payload, headers=headers)
print(f'superset url: {login_res.url}')
#print(f'Login-response: {login_res.text}')
print(login_res.json())
print(f'Login-response: {login_res.text}')
access_token = login_res.json().get("access_token")

headers.update(
    {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
        'Referer': login_url
    }
)

if login_res.status_code != 200:
    print(f'login failed: {login_res.status_code} - {login_res.reason}')
else:
    print('login successful!')


#Fetch CSRF token
csrf_response = session.get(csrf_url, headers=headers)
#print(f'csrf_status_code: {csrf_response.status_code}, csrf_reason: {csrf_response.reason}')
#print(f'csrf_text: {csrf_response.text}')
#print(f'redirect_history: {csrf_response.history}')
#print(session.cookies)
csrf_response_json = csrf_response.json()
csrf_token = csrf_response_json.get("result") 

#API call with CSRF token
headers.update(
    {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
    }
)


#exception block if token not fetched
if not csrf_token:
    print('Failed to fetch token')
else:
    print('CSRF token fetched successfully!')


response = session.get(api_url, headers=headers, allow_redirects = True) 
response.text 

try:
    data = response.json()
    print(f'fetching data: {data}')
    
except ValueError:
    print(f'response is not JSON, printing raw response') 
    print(response.text)

As I'm using Superset version 4.0.1, I'm getting charts, datasets, dashboard, etc. info
while using api_url = f'{superset_url}/api/v1/chart'
But when using
api_url = f'{superset_url}/api/v1/role' or for that matter api_url = f'{superset_url}/api/v1/user' I'm getting 404 error.
Why is it so? Am I using the correct version or is this version (version 4.0.1) compatible only to get access to the charts, datasets, dashboard and not to the user or role info.
I'm admin and have all permissions in the superset and have enabled
FAB_ADD_SECURITY_API = True
